# Can references be made without declaring a variable first?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, reference, perl-data-structures

I have this code that works

```
my @new = keys %h1;
my @old = keys %h2;

function(\@new, \@old);
```

but can it be done without having to declare variables first?

`function` must have its arguments as *references*.

Comment: Because you can't really "just try it" without knowing what to try?

Comment: She could at least have tried to replace @new and @old with the expressions on the RHS. Then, if perl complained, she could have asked why and how to prevent it.

Comment: (1) Who's to say she didn't try it? If it were that easy, yeah, i'd be with you -- but it's not. (2) Personally, when i find myself trying random combinations of syntax in the hopes one will work, i'm *already lost* and probably should have asked for help sooner. (3) I doubt she (or anyone with a job to get done) cares why `function(\keys(%h1), \keys(%h2))` doesn't work -- just that it doesn't.  Her goal is still clear, and not muddied by the tortured syntax of a thousand useless tries. (4) She came with a clear question and a problem that's not exactly easy to google. She has my upvote.

Comment: @cHao - I agree with you on most points. Though, if one seeks help it is always a good idea to indicate what one has tried already. Apart from that, best help is IMHO to help someone to help him- or herself in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my %test = (key1 => "value",key2 => "value2");
my %test2 = (key3 => "value3",key4 => "value4");

test_sub([keys %test], [keys %test2]);

sub test_sub{
 my $ref_arr = shift;
 my $ref_arr2 = shift;
 print Dumper($ref_arr);
 print Dumper($ref_arr2);
}
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'key2',
          'key1'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          'key4',
          'key3'
        ];
```

Answer (score 6):

```
function([ keys %h1 ], [ keys %h2 ]);
```

From [`perldoc perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References):

> A reference to an anonymous array can
>   be created using square brackets:
>
> $arrayref = [1, 2, ['a', 'b', 'c']];